# Constructor on child class being ignored in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to derive a class from `numpy.recarray` with different constructor arguments:

```
import numpy as np

class Table(np.recarray):
    def __init__(self,
                 silly_arg = ['nope']):
      print "Table.__init__"

      super(Table, self).__init__(shape = 10, dtype = [('r', np.float64), ('v', np.float64)])

t = Table()
```

However, it does not obey my `print` instruction, and instead gives an error:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    t = Table()
TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I assume this is because recarray has a `__new__` method in addition to its `__init__`, and new is being called to allocate it before construction actually happens.

Note that I am using Python 2.7.

How can I do this correctly? The arguments passed to recarray's allocation depend on the arguments passed to Table during construction.

Comment: Define `__new__`, not `__init__` (except you should probably reconsider whether you really want to do this, because getting array subclasses right takes a lot more work and expertise than you'd think).

Comment: @user2357112 I write a lot of Python C extensions by hand. This seems like something I'd probably need to do in C, no? I mean, `__new__` is usually written in C, isn't it?

Comment: Overriding C `__new__` methods with Python `__new__` methods is pretty normal. Writing a `__new__` in Python for a class whose only C ancestor is `object` would be unusual, though.

Comment: @user2357112 What would something like that look like for a numpy array-based type?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html